# Number of terms in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Number of terms in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5$?

Possible solution: $(5 \cdot 3)+1=16$

---

Please note that this has been edited to reflect the poster's original intention. Several of the comments and answers reflect an alternative interpretation of the original question, to find the number of terms of the rather different expression $(1+x_1+x_2+x_3)^5$. [See comments]

Comment: Does the edit achieve what you want? The question as originally posed is unclear, and this edit is just one way of resolving the ambiguity. Your answer of $16$ would make sense if you were looking at $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5$ because terms would range from $x^0$ to $x^{15}$.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) could help, especially [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_multinomial_coefficients).

Comment: @MarkBennet - I'm sorry I did mean $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5$. I'm new to the site and am still getting used to the notations and symbols. I came across this question in something i was reading. I saw the solution but didn't completely understand it. Maybe you could shed some light on it ??

Comment: this question can be easily solved by stars and bars formula for a quick reference wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+b+c+d+\cdots m \;terms)^n$$

number of terms in expansion of above polynomial :$\dfrac{(n+(m-1))!}{n!(m-1)!}$

so in expansion of$(1+x_1+x_2+x_3)^5$ there are 
$m=4$ $n=5$
$$\dfrac{(5+(4-1))!}{5!(4-1)!}$$
$$\dfrac{8!}{5! 3!}$$
$$\dfrac{8\times 7\times 6}{ 3\times 2}$$
$$56\;terms$$

Comment: You are wrong, you can check with Mathematica that after simplification there will be only 16 terms

Comment: Actually I gave the answer of $(1+x_1+x_2+x_3)^5$.The question was edited after.I am updating my answer ASAP

Answer (score 1):

To answer the intended question, which is more straightforward than the alternative:

Note that in the expression $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5$ the powers of $x$ range from $0$ $(x^0=1)$ to $15$. Gathering the terms together it is easy to see that each power does occur, so there are indeed $16$ terms.